# Collecting and using data returned from a http Curl (php) Post

Tags: php, curl

I need assistance with using the data returned after a http post.
Below is my current post code that posts the data to a specific website

```
<?php
//extract data from the post
extract($_POST);

//set POST variables
$url = 'https://test.com';
$fields = array(
                        'surname' => urlencode($surname),
                        'first_name' => urlencode($first_name),
                        'dob' => urlencode($dob),
                        'email' => urlencode($email),
                        'home_phone' => urlencode($home_phone),
                        'mobile_phone' => urlencode($mobile_phone),
                        'work_phone' => urlencode($work_phone),
                        'postcode' => urlencode($postcode),
                        'leadid' => urlencode(123),
                        'affid' => urlencode(123),
                        'subid' => urlencode(123),
                        'bank_acno' => urlencode($bank_acno),
                        'bank_sort' => urlencode($bank_sort),
                        'amount_required' => urlencode($amount_required),

                );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

I get either one of 2 response's - {result:true} or {result:false}

I need to know is how to do the following :

When I get a {result:true} I want to redirect to url "http://thisurl.com"
When I get a {result:false} I want to return a response "Denied"

Please note the response is not json , it is just returned in that format.

Comment: is the returned data genuine json? Incidentally, you might wish to look at http_build_query in the php docs for building your post data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check what `$result` variable contains and then make the redirect or show denied message according to situation:

```
<?php
//extract data from the post
extract($_POST);

//set POST variables
$url = 'https://test.com';
$fields = array(
                        'surname' => urlencode($surname),
                        'first_name' => urlencode($first_name),
                        'dob' => urlencode($dob),
                        'email' => urlencode($email),
                        'home_phone' => urlencode($home_phone),
                        'mobile_phone' => urlencode($mobile_phone),
                        'work_phone' => urlencode($work_phone),
                        'postcode' => urlencode($postcode),
                        'leadid' => urlencode(123),
                        'affid' => urlencode(123),
                        'subid' => urlencode(123),
                        'bank_acno' => urlencode($bank_acno),
                        'bank_sort' => urlencode($bank_sort),
                        'amount_required' => urlencode($amount_required),

                );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

$result_true   = 'true';
$check_true = strpos($result, $result_true);

if ($check_true !== false) {
     header('Location: http://url.com');
     die;
}

$result_false   = 'false';
$check_false = strpos($result, $result_false);

if ($check_false !== false) {
     echo "Denied";
}
```

And in your code you've used:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
```

But in php.net manual:

> CURLOPT_POST: TRUE to do a regular HTTP POST. This POST is the normal
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded kind, most commonly used by HTML
>   forms.

So counting fields is not the proper way to do this it could be TRUE or FALSE not the count. Of course if `$fields` array is empty result will be `0` which is equal to `FALSE` or if it's 1 then it's `1` (`TRUE`) but when the result of the count is greater than `1` that's makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you motto , can you provide me with a complete solution. Add you solution to my code, as i dnt know where to put it

Comment: @MaxPayneUK add this after the last segment of your code. Between curl_close and closing tag '?>'

Comment: @MaxPayneUK i've updated my answer. let me know if it's correct for you.

Comment: sorry , but it does nothing. it just outsputs {result:true} or {result:false}

Comment: @MaxPayneUK ok, that's probably because i've used $response instead of $result. fixed now

Comment: i have re tested it and still it does the same thing. Just to make a note the result returned is not true or false its {result:true} & {result:false}. i tryed replacing the true with " {result:true} " and same with the false, but it seems not to be running that part of the script at all

Comment: @MaxPayneUK i've tested for both conditions and it works without problem. probably there are some differences between your actual code and the code on here.